# how to add all integer values of string using java?

Tags: java, sum

```
String something = "123e45,j, _122";
            int length = something.length();
            String result = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                Character character = something.charAt(i);
                if (Character.isDigit(character)) {
                    result += character;
                }
            }
//            out.println("result is:"+result);
```

Here I'm getting value in resut as:1`2345122` but I need to calculate sum of all values ,that is 20.

Comment: @peter.petrov,in result string i have 12345122 for this sting i need to calculate sum of all integers(1+2+3+4+5+1+2+2=20)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Change type of result to int.
2. Parse the char to an integer. If you only cast the char to an integer, you add the ascii value of this character to your result.

   ```
   String something = "123e45,j, _122";
   int length = something.length();
   int result = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
       Character character = something.charAt(i);
       if (Character.isDigit(character)) {
           result += Character.getNumericValue(character);
       }
   }
   System.out.println("result is: "+result);
   ```

Output: `result is: 20`

Answer (score 4):

you can use regex like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "123e45,j, _122";
    int val = 0;
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d"); // match single digit
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    while (m.find()) {            // for all digits
        val = val + Integer.parseInt(m.group()); // covert each String (digit) into numeric value and add to count

    }
    System.out.println(val);
}

O/P :
20
```

Answer (score 0):

You could stay with your loop and use [`StringUtils.isNumeric()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isNumeric(java.lang.CharSequence))

Comment: Its totally off topic. But I wonder why do I need to import an entire new external jar/API just for a single method that I can do it myself wth just a few lines of code.

Comment: Use more Apache Commons is not necessary in this circumstance.

Comment: @user3505725 - why is this off-topic? And why use libraries, because of a Don't Repeat Yourself principle. But if you like, you can re-invent wheel for yourself ;-)

Comment: @donhuvy yes it is not *necessary*, but you can use it if you want to. The accepted answer does it using Character's method.

Comment: @EelLee...Why do you think it's re-inventing the wheel for just a couple of lines of code...If my requirement is only to have one function with less than 10 lines of code which I can write myself , Why the heck I should import the entire jar file into my project just for a single method.

Comment: @user3505725 well, I think you will import only necessary classes, not the entire .jar. Where is the problem in that? In this particular case, you could use another method, but do you really want to write **every** 10-liner instead of use an existing method? How long will you write it - half an hour? Five minutes? Why not know the libraries and do this in 10 seconds? Where is the point in writing an existing snippet once again?

Comment: @Eel Lee Importing new libraries means adding an extra dependency to the project. My point is  that , If i know that I can do a task in 5 min with just a couple of lines of code, why should I again unnecessarily add a whole new extra orphan dependency to my project just for a single method? Knowing and Adding the libraries is fine ? But at what cost ?

Answer (score 0):

```
String something = "123e45,j, _122";
        int length = something.length();
        int sum=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            Character character = something.charAt(i);
            if (Character.isDigit(character)) {
                sum+= Integer.parseInt( Character.toString(character) );
            }
        }
```

//           out.println("result is:"+sum);

This works. sum is an integer now you can use it to perform calculations or you can parse it to String again with: `String result = String.valueOf(sum);`

Answer (score 0):

While the solutions of others will get you the desired result with the help of some libraries and wrappers, but I think once you get what happens in this piece of code, your basic understanding of the other code pieces increases as well.

```
int sumString(String some) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < some.length(); i++)
        sum += (some.charAt(i) >= '0' && some.charAt(i) <= '9') ? (some.charAt(i) - '0') : 0; 
    return sum;
}
```

In short: for every index of the string, check of the character is numeric by checking if the character value is between `0` and `9`. If it is, convert it into its integer value by subtracting the ASCII value of `0` (`0` = 48 and `9` = 57, and if we subtract 48 to 48, you get 0, and 57 - 48 = 9)